# Detect if number is a multiple of 7 or contains the number 7

Tags: java

I read a book about challenges in Java, and it gives the next question:

create a function, which get a number as argument, and detect if number is a multiple of 7 or contains the number 7.

The signature is: `public boolean find7(int num)`

I create this function, when the number is between 0 to 99, by the next condition:

```
if (num mod 7 == 0 || num / 10 ==7 || num mod 10 == 7)
   return true;
```

But what with number which is greater than 99? like 177, or 709? How can I detect it?

Comment: Haha that's the drinking game "Buzz"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably best to leave strings out of this:

```
public static boolean check(final int n) {
    int m = Math.abs(n);
    while (m > 0) {
        if (m % 10 == 7)
            return true;

        m /= 10;
    }

    return n % 7 == 0;
}
```

The `while`-loop checks each digit and tests if it is 7; if it is, we return true and if it isn't, we continue. We reach the final return statement only if none of the digits were 7, at which point we return whether the number is a multiple of 7.

Comment: Downvoter, please leave a comment. I'd like to know what's wrong with my answer so I can fix it!

Comment: +1. But that only works for positive integers. So may you should change to `int m = Math.abs(n);`

Comment: @ZouZou Thanks, I made that change.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (num % 7 ==0 || ("" + num).contains("7") ){
    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you would convert it to a `String` it would not be considered a challenge anymore, as neither that or dividing by 7 is a challenge.

Comment: @skiwi One line of code vs 6-10 lines of code. I rest my case.

Answer (score 2):

You can extend your approach to numbers above 100 like this:

```
public boolean find7(int num) {
    // support for negative integers
    num = Math.abs(num);

    // check if num is a multiple of 7
    if (num % 7 == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    // check to see if num contains 7
    while (num > 1) {
        // if the last digit is 7, return true
        if (num % 10 == 7) {
            return true;
        }

        // truncate the last digit
        num /= 10
    }

    // the number is not a multiple of 7 and it does not contain 7
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Check ZouZou comment on @arshajii answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
    if(Integer.toString(num).contains("7") || ...){

    }
```

Comment: +1 - The best and simplest answer.  Why reinvent a wheel when the `Integer` and `String` class between them already have the right functionality.  It is a mistake to try and solve this without using `String`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as checking if the number is divisible by 7, you're fine.
If you want to check if it contains the 7 digit, I think the easiest approach would be to treat the number as a String:

```
public boolean find7(int num) {
    // check if it's a multiple of 7:
    if (num % 7 == 0) {
        return true;
    }

    // if it's not, check if it contains the character 7:
    return String.valueOf(num).contains("7");
}
```

Comment: If you would convert it to a `String` it would not be considered a challenge anymore, as neither that or dividing by 7 is a challenge.

Answer (score 0):

For detecting if number is multiple of 7:

```
boolean isMultiple = x % 7 == 0
```

For detecting digit:

Convert it to `String` and use `String.contains()`

or

Create digit `List` like this:

```
private List<Integer> getDigitList(int number){
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        int leftover = number;
        while (leftover != 0){
            int result = leftover % 10;
            leftover = (leftover - result)/10;
            list.add(result)
        }
        assert leftover == 0;

        return list;
    }
```